# Inconsistency of SCDF Stream Deployment status

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

Requests to deploy an SCDF Stream succeed, however, this results in a wrong combination of statuses:

- deployment claims "DEPLOYED",
- while the overall status of the Stream remains "UNDEDPLOYED"

Further attempts to deploy the same stream fail with "Failed to upload the package. Package [XXXX-notif-ftm-dev:1.0.0] in Repository [local] already exists." error message. Deletion of the deployment through a REST call enables deployments again, but they result in the same.

What can we debug this situation?

SCDF version is 2.5.3.RELEASE. It runs in Kubernetes and the Stream is meant to be deployed to another namespace

[image: inconsistent status]

Comment: Hi, This looks like a bug or some inconsistencies with Skipper server when it calculates the stream status. Could you create an issue here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues with the steps you can repeat this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I've discovered that for various reasons the pods of the deployed Streams cannot be scheduled. Before reporting an issue in GitHub, I'd like to see if resolving these problems will "help" SCDF to report the stream status correctly. If it does or not, still, SCDF should not get confused ;)

Comment: Indeed, the problem with the inconsistent status appears only when pods of the Stream cannot be created. When Pod is created but fails the Stream deployment status is correct.